# Unit Testing A Moment Date - Memory Address Issues?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, momentjs

The problem?
I am trying to test a method that uses the moment.subtract() method which takes 1 day off the current date. Firstly, the subtract method provided to us by Moment only manipulates the date, it does not create a new date, so no new memory address location. When trying to test this method, I am getting the following expectation error:

`[ Wed Jun 20 2018 09:14:52 GMT+0100 ]
but actual calls were
[ Wed Jun 20 2018 09:14:52 GMT+0100 ]`

Weird right?

The only thing I can think of is somewhere in my code the date reference is changing. I will place my code below with the unit test as well

```
public prevDate = () => {
  this.datePickerService.changeDate(this.date.subtract(1, 'day'));
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.date = this.datePickerService.date; // Is this the problem?
}
```

Unit tests:

```
describe('When the prevDate method is called', () => {
   setupComponent();

   it('should show yesterdays date', () => {
     spyOn(datePickerService, 'changeDate');
     datePickerService.date = moment();
     component.prevDate();
 expect(datePickerService.changeDate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(datePickerService.date.add(-1, 'days'));
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test doesn't pass because you're not using the same arguments :

```
this.datePickerService.changeDate(this.date.subtract(1, 'day'));
------------
.toHaveBeenCalledWith(datePickerService.date.add(-1, 'days'))
```

use this instead :

```
.toHaveBeenCalledWith(component.date.subtract(1, 'day'))
```

Comment: Hello trichetriche, I had the same idea earlier as well but I found the tests passed everytime

Comment: Well that's kind of the purpose ... It works when the arguments match (this case), and it doesn't work when the arguments mismatch (your case). This is made to prevent side effects.